# Building helixes with different torsion values

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I have following helix parametrization:
$$
x(t)= r\cos(t)
$$
$$
y(t)= r\sin(t)
$$
$$
z(t)= h\cdot t
$$
For example I have $ r=1 $ and $ h = 0.05 $

Then my torsion T will be:
$$
T = \frac{h}{r^2+h^2} = \frac{0.05}{1+0.05^2} \approx 0.0476
$$
My question is how can I build helixes with $ 0.1T, 0.2T, -0.1T, -0.1T $

I dont get how changing torsion analytically change position of points of the helix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $r$ is constant, you can find the $h$ corresponding to a given $T$ by solving for $h$ in the equation
$$
T = \frac{h}{r^2 + h^2}
$$
Rearranging, we get $Th^2 - h + Tr^2 =0$. This has real roots only when $r \le 1/(2T)$.

One possible solution is $r=h=1/(2T)$.

Answer (score 1):

From $T=h/(r^2+h^2)$ we get
$$r^2+\left(h-\frac{1}{2T}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4T^2},$$
that is, for given $T$ all possible values for $r$ and $h$ lie on a circle centered in $(0,1/2T)$ with radius $1/2T$.